# SharePoint Online Provider Hosted app Many to Many Relation lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I working in SharePoint Online Provider Hosted app

I have two lists having a many to many relationship

My question is: What is best way to implement this? 
By lookup field or list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookup columns to model one-to-many relationships or one-to-one relationships between lists. However, if you require a many-to-many relationship between entities in your data model, lookup columns alone are insufficient for defining the relationship. While you could use custom user interface components to manage the relationship, a better approach is to normalize the data model. Just as you would add a join table to normalize a many-to-many relationship in a relational database, you can add a join list to normalize a many-to-many relationship between SharePoint lists.

For more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798409.aspx

http://www.infowisesolutions.com/blog/comments.aspx?ArticleId=91

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_27777583.html

Comment: if i use multiple value lookup field. it's low performance?

Comment: How many items are there in library?

Comment: This is the only option to provide relations between lists.

Comment: Relation between Courses list and Instructors list

Comment: You have to define some relation between these lists . so you need lookup column